# conda build gives "DLL load failed while importing etree", but only from script

Tags: python, conda, elementtree

TL;DR: Contrast two tests executed during `conda build`: The first is a script that fails on `from lxml import etree`. The other is simply `python -c "from lxml import etree` and succeeds. What could be the reason?

When `conda build`ing my package, one test is running one of my entrypoints. It fails on the line `from lxml import etree` with `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing etree: The specified module could not be found.` However, another test is simply `python -c "from lxml import etree"`, which works. (Also, when I activate the test environment that `conda build` created in a shell [after `conda deactivate`ing the `base` environment to be at `CONDA_SHLVL` 1 like `conda build` is], `python -c "from lxml import etree"` works. Running the script on the command line in `conda build`'s test environment also works.) *The same import in the same environment in the same `conda build` run succeeds or fails!* The failure must be due to something that happens when running the script - what could that be?

The `meta.yaml` contains `lxml` in the `requirements.run` section. It is also reported as being installed into the test environment by `conda build`. When I `conda list` the environment, `lxml` is there. The error message does not say which DLL is missing. My guess is `libxml2.dll` from the eponymous package upon which `lxml` depends. It is also reported first as getting, then as being installed.

This thread https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87339 lists where DLLs are actually searched by Python:

- the loaded extension module's directory
- the application directory (e.g. that of python.exe)
- the user DLL search directories that get added by
  SetDllDirectory() and AddDllDirectory(), such as with
  os.add_dll_directory()
- %SystemRoot%\System32

My analysis so far: The first is identical since the environment is identical, second could differ but doesn't (see debug output below), fourth is also identical. As for the third, if one of the two context could be suspected to call `os.add_dll_directory()` before the import, it would be the script IMHO, where it *doesn't* work. The context where it works is a simple `python -c "from lxml import etree"` as its own test, where no `os.add_dll_directory()` could have been called.

Start of the relevant script (notice my debugging code):

```
#!${CONDA_PREFIX}/python -u
'''...'''
    
import os, sys
sys.stderr.write( f"executable {sys.executable}\n" )
sys.stderr.write( f"CONDA_PREFIX: {os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX']}\n" )
sys.stderr.write( f"CONDA_SHLVL: {os.environ['CONDA_SHLVL']}\n" )
sys.stderr.write( f"PATH: {os.environ['PATH']}\n" )
if '_' in os.environ:
    sys.stderr.write( f"_: {os.environ['_']}\n" )
from lxml import etree
```

Relevant section from `conda build` output

```
Worked
executable C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\python.exe
CONDA_PREFIX: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env
CONDA_SHLVL: 1
PATH: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\condabin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Library\usr\bin;.;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\condabin;H:\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;H:\bin;C:\Programs\OpenSCAD;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q8;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\jpoppinga\OneDrive - Materialise NV\Tools;C:\Users\jpoppinga\OneDrive - Materialise NV\Programs;C:\Programs\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Inkscape;C:\Programs\mupdf-1.16.0-windows;C:\Program Files\Materialise\Inspector 3.3;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;C:\Users\jpoppinga\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive;C:\Programs\xmlstarlet-1.6.1;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Programs\MPlayer-corei7-r38328+g30322ebe3c;C:\Program Files\Notepad++;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Users\jpoppinga\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\jpoppinga\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\jpoppinga\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
_: C:/ProgramData/Miniconda3/Scripts/conda.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Scripts\mgx-analyse-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('steel==12.0.0a0', 'console_scripts', 'mgx-analyse')())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\Scripts\mgx-analyse-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 86, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env\lib\site-packages\steel\scripts\mgx_analyse.py", line 20, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing etree: The specified module could not be found.
```

`meta.yaml`:

```
package:
  name: steel
  version: {{ load_setup_py_data().version }}

source:
  git_rev: HEAD
  git_url: ..
  path: .

requirements:
  build:
    - python 3.10
    - jinja2
    - pyyaml
  host:
    - python 3.10
    - setuptools
    - jinja2
    - pyyaml

  run:
    - trimesh
    - rtree # Soft trimesh dependency
    - scipy # ditto
    - networkx # ditto
    - tqdm # progress bar
    - kdtree # efficient caching
    - shapely
    - lxml=4.8.0
    - pandas
    - joblib
    - open3d=0.14.1 # from channel open3d-admin - add to your config

test:
  commands:
    - surf --help
    - surf --version
    - propseg --help
    - volt --help
    - stl2svg --help
    - python -c "from lxml import etree; import sys; sys.stderr.write('Worked\n')" # <-- This test works
    - mgx-analyse --help  # <-- This test fails on "from lxml import etree"
    - remesh --help
    - histl --help
  imports:
    - lxml.etree
    - steel
    - steel.surface
    - steel.scripts
    - steel.geom
    - steel.mesh
    - steel.util
    - steel.features
```

`conda info` of the build environment:

```
     active environment : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\build\conda-bld\steel_1661772446411\_test_env
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\jpoppinga\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\jpoppinga\.condarc
          conda version : 4.14.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/open3d-admin/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/open3d-admin/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\jpoppinga\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\jpoppinga\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\jpoppinga\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\jpoppinga\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.14.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: That's a weird `requirements:` section, re: `host` and `build` duplications; maybe review [the distinct purposes of the various subsections](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#requirements-section). It may help to consult [existing Conda Forge recipes](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Amerged) for reference. Also, `conda info` really gives no insight into active environments (most of its output is about **base**); a `conda list` output would be more appropriate.

Comment: @merv I tried removing each line. I could only get rid of the `python` in `build`, each other removed line would cause `conda build .` to fail. `pyyaml` and `jinja2` are used in the `setup.py` - maybe that plays a role.

Comment: I don't have an answer but thanks for posting this, since it seems impossible to debug what the real problem is, when an import fails